# How to logout correct in stateless Vaadin Fusion 22 project with oauth2

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-fusion, vaadin22, hilla

I set up a project to be stateless according to this documentation https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/fusion/security/spring-stateless

Authtorization set up through Keycloak:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
// Set default security policy that permits Vaadin internal requests and
// denies all other
super.configure(http);

http.sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

http
    // Enable OAuth2 login
    .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login.clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository)
        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint -> userInfoEndpoint
            // Use a custom authorities mapper to get the roles from the identity provider
            // into the Authentication token
            .userAuthoritiesMapper(authoritiesMapper))
        // Use a Vaadin aware authentication success handler
        .successHandler(new VaadinSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()))
    // Configure logout
    .logout(logout -> logout
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())

        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET")));

setStatelessAuthentication(http,
new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(authSecret),
JwsAlgorithms.HS256),
"com.my.app");

}

private OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler = new 
OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(
    clientRegistrationRepository);
logoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}/");
return logoutSuccessHandler;
}
```

Authentification works fine, we can see jwt tokens in cookies
[jwt tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cShO.png)

But when I click to logout button, I am still logged in.
There is a logout function as described here https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/fusion/security/authentication-offline/#removing-an-expired-authentication

```html
export async function logout() {
  setSessionExpired();
  await logoutImpl();
  appStore.clearUserInfo();
  location.href = '/logout';
}
```

Comment: I don't know but your method does not look like the one in the documentation.

Comment: It looks like OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler doesn't know about JWT

Comment: Hi @Roman. Have you found a solution how to properly configure Vaadin with Keycloak and JWT? If so, could you please share the configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately, no